# Which Mythic/Story Path and Class in Pathfinder: WotR are the most bug-free?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

Which mythic/story path and class have been played through or tested the most (for example, mythic paths like 'Living Legend', 'Angel' and classes like paladin or monk), and which were most bug free? I feel like it would help if we knew, so that those of us who just want to have fun without becoming unpaid beta testers can play it on our first round while waiting for everything else to get fixed.

I'm sure that the game was played through at least once using one of the beta-tested mythic paths and classes. That might explain why some of the reviewers said there were 'no bugs at all'.

I've already asked this question in the Steam forums, but to no avail. Hopefully someone here can help with this!

No spoilers, please. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge all mythic paths work fine for the crusade. Lich is the only with significant mechanics changes compared to the others.

The problem with the Lich Mythic Path was fixed in last Fridays patch. The comments were also exaggerated, it wasn't completely broken, the people who said that were probably bad at handling the crusade mechanics and would have run into trouble with every other mythic path as well.

The Lich mythic path nets you necromancy, which reduces your ability to recruit normal units but grants you undead troops for each victory. The actual bug was, that you didn't get those troops, if you had them in your army, i.e. you would only get skeletons or zombies if the army you used contained no skeletons or zombies. I was easily able to play around that by not using the undead troops and just relying on my normal army; I built up my undead army while still progressing. This bug was fixed and now works correctly.

The second issue people complained about was, that you didn't get enough of those troops, which is simply not true. You receive enemy troop value/275 skeletons or zombies, which some people interpreted as actual number of troops (e.g. a powerful demon has a value of about 150, so killing two of those is a skeleton, in the minds of those people, you'd have to kill 275 of those demons to get a skeleton). You usually get between 10-30 undead per victory in chapter 3, which is a decent number.

Lich is harder to play than other the mythic paths, as your reinforcements are more limited and you have to win more fights without actual losses, but it's definitely not broken. I really want to reiterate, that the main issue is people being bad at the crusade. I've read many people complain about constant powerful demon attacks right after the start of Chapter 3 and they don't know how to handle it. While it's true, that the demons attack you fairly frequently, none of the armies the demons sent to me so far posed any challenge at all.

Comment: Hi, Dulkan,
Thanks for answering! It's not just the crusade though: I heard that a lot of other paths are bugged (story flags not working properly, some spells acting in a quirky/glitchy manner). Do you have any mythic paths and classes to recommend that have as few bugs as possible (and I don't mean just inside crusade)? :)

Comment: Lich is working fine for me and I'm 100 hours in. If you want to play it safe, go for Angel or Demon, as those are probably the most commonly played paths. But I'd be surprised if you find major bugs in any of the paths. Pathfinder is an incredibly complex game, so stuff may break depending on a gigantic number of variables. I highly doubt, that any particular mythic path is more prone to bugs than others. Gold Dragon seems to have some bugs, but that's a late game path anyway and Aeon is apparently a bit on the weak side compared to other paths.